# mxmlc generates different binarys (swf) even with no code changes

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm running svn and sending swf files to my client.
I realized that even without code modifications, the swf generated by mxmlc seems to be different everytime.

Is it possible to make it generate the same swf file (so it does not require a svn commit) if there are no code changes?

below is how I generate my swf.

mxmlc -load-config+=obj\Sample.xml -debug=true -incremental=true -benchmark=false -define=CONFIG::debugging,true -o bin\Sample.swf

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the build timestamp is embedded into the SWF, and then the binary is compressed.  This will cause subtle variations in compression used for the binary, and so it will often change.

I don't know of a way around this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wonder if there is a solution to this.